# mpich2 2 executables standard output

Tags: gdb, stdout, mpich

I need to launch 2 executables (program1 and program2) with the same mpirun (mpich) command, and I'm trying to debug program1 with gdb. I use this command:

`mpirun -n 1 gdb program1 : -n 1 program2`

The command correctly opens the gdb console, but if I set a breakpoint somewhere after mpi_init, the screen gets flooded with the standard output of program2. Is there a simple way to redirect the standard output of program2 (only program2) to a file?

My fast solution was to hard-code a cut of stdout in program2, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant one ...

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

1. create a **wrapper.sh** that redirect the stdout and stderr to the file **output** :

```
cat > wrapper.sh << EOF
#!/bin/bash
\$* 1>>output 2>&1
EOF
```

2. make it executable

```
chmod +x wrapper.sh
```

3. mpirun with the wrapper

```
mpirun -n 1 gdb program1 : -n 1 ./wrapper.sh program2
```